# Serverless - Setting the authorization type to CUSTOM or COGNITO_USER_POOLS requires a valid authorizer

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, serverless

I have a problem when attaching custom authorizer on API gateway endpoint. Here is my scenario step :

1. Create custom authorizer (using lambda function).
2. Create new endpoint with integration type as HTTP.
3. Set AuthorizationType as CUSTOM

How I attach my custom authorizer on serverless yaml?

- I try using AuthorizerId, got error “ProxyMethod - Invalid authorizer ID specified. Setting the authorization type to CUSTOM or COGNITO_USER_POOLS requires a valid authorizer.”
- I didn’t find example code on [serverless documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nSK2g.jpg) for my scenario above
- I try to follow [AWS docs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJlV2.jpg). It explains to use AuthorizerId, but not sure whether serverless support it or not.

Could someone assist me with this?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should create the Authorizer first. The you will got an authorizer id which could be used in your config.

```
Resources:
    authorizer:
      Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Authorizer
      Properties: 
        AuthorizerResultTtlInSeconds: 0
        AuthorizerUri: !Join
          - ''
          - - 'arn:aws:apigateway:'
            - '{region}'
            - ':lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/'
            - 'arn:aws:lambda:{region}:'
            - Ref: AWS::AccountId
            - ':function:customAuthorizer'
            - '/invocations'
        Name: authorizer
        RestApiId: {restApiId}
  

Outputs:
    authorizerId:
      Description: "API Gateway Auth Id"
      Value: !Ref authorizer
      Export:
        Name: !Join
          - '-'
          - - !Ref AWS::StackName
            - AuthorizerId
```